# Incorrect syntax ','

Tags: vb.net

I have an incorrect syntax error n my code below.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("ເລືອກໂຕະທີ່ຕ້ອງການຊຳລະ")
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("ເລືອກສິນຄ້າ")
        ElseIf TextBox2.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("ເລືອກຈຳນວນສິນຄ້າ")
        Else
            Dim OrderData As Date
            OrderData = FormatDateTime(Now, DateFormat.ShortDate)
            Dim cnsql = "insert into TbOrderDetail values(" & Label1.Text & ","
            cnsql &= "" & ProductID & "," & TextBox2.Text & ","
            cnsql &= "" & Label2.Text & ")"
            SQL.ManageData(cnsql)
        End If
        showData()
        showData22()
        TextBox2.Focus()
    End Sub
```

Comment: You are open for sql injection, but apart form that i don't see the incorrect syntax. Can you tell us the line number? I assume it is in `SQL.ManageData`.

Comment: what part has the syntax error? if that's the error, the program will lead you to the line that caused the error. please tell us where.

Comment: I click to btn order product then it shows incorrect syntax ','.
and SQLCon.open() the connection was not closed. the connection's current state is open @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you need to define the `.TEXT` properties as text strings inside your sql code. Try this instead:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("ເລືອກໂຕະທີ່ຕ້ອງການຊຳລະ")
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("ເລືອກສິນຄ້າ")
        ElseIf TextBox2.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("ເລືອກຈຳນວນສິນຄ້າ")
        Else
            Dim OrderData As Date
            OrderData = FormatDateTime(Now, DateFormat.ShortDate)
            Dim cnsql = "insert into TbOrderDetail values('" & Label1.Text & "',"
            cnsql &= "" & ProductID & ",'" & TextBox2.Text & "',"
            cnsql &= "'" & Label2.Text & "')"
            SQL.ManageData(cnsql)
        End If
        showData()
        showData22()
        TextBox2.Focus()
    End Sub
```

I leave the `ProductID` out, as it should be an integer for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating strings to build your sql query you should always use parameterized queries. On that way you prevent sql-injection and localization issues. The database has to infer the type of your parameters from their values which can lead to incorrect casts or performance issues.

Maybe you have to wrap text values in apostrophes, but instead of that use sql-parameters as already mentioned:

```
Using con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.Default.ConnectionString)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into TbOrderDetail values(@ProductID, @Column2, @Column3)", con)
        Dim p As New SqlParameter("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int)
        p.Value = ProductID
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
        p = SqlParameter("@Column2", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        p.Value = TextBox2.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
        p = SqlParameter("@Column3", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        p.Value = Label2.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
        con.Open()
        Dim insertedCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write the column names next to your

insert into TbOrderDetail

insert into TbOrderDetail (columnname1, columnname2) VALUES (value1, value2)